# Oracle NUMTOYMINTERVAL

Tags: oracle11g

Can someone explain the logic of NUMTOYMINTERVAL . I went through various websites, but could not get it.

Can you please explain on below specific examples

```
 select (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(30,'month')) from dual;   
 select (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(30,'YEAR')) from dual; 
 PARTITION BY RANGE (RECORDDATE) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This site here gives a good explanation:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Interval

> INTERVAL datatype is a data type used to store a period of time. There are 2 kinds of interval: INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH, to store a difference in years and months, and INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, to store a difference in days, hours, minutes and seconds.

it provides a way of indicating a `LENGTH` of time .. either `YEAR/MONTH` (`NUMTOYMINTERVAL`)  or days/hours/min/secods: (`TO_DSINTERVAL`)

So in your first example:

```
  SQL > select (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(30,'month')) from dual;
  -------------- More --------------

  (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(30,'MONTH'))
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  +000000002-06

  1 row selected.
```

It returns an `INTERVAL` representing the length of time for "30 months" .. the result is showing "2 years and 6 months" ..

On a side note, this post by Tom Kyte is interesting, he recommends avoid using `NUMTOYMINTERVAL` due to behaviour near end of months

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:68920891856765

> I do not recommend using the NUMTOYMINTERVAL function. The reason has to do with how the 
>   functions behave at the months end.